# VBA - PasteSpecial Error and moving to next row in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to loop through a number of word documents in a folder, and add some information from the word tables to the excel sheet. Right now I have this:

```
Private Sub Loop_WordToExcel()

    Dim WdApp As Object
    Dim wddoc As Object
    Dim docName As String
    Dim strFile As String
    Dim directory As String

    directory = "c:\path\to\folder"
    strFile = Dir(directory & "*.*")
    Set WdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")

    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Enter row", Type:=8)

    'Do While strFile <> ""

        Set wddoc = WdApp.Documents.Open(Filename:=directory & strFile)


        rng.Cells(1) = wddoc.Name

        'First Name
        wddoc.Tables(1).Cell(1, 3).Range.Copy
        rng.Cells(2).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)

        WdApp.ActiveDocument.Close SaveChanges:=False
        strFile = Dir

        Loop

End Sub
```

I have two questions.
1. My first issue is a Run-time error '1004': PasteSpecial method of Range class failed
2. At the end of the loop, how to I advance to the next row for the next word document information to be pasted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct syntax while copying from Word is given, May try

```
Sub Loop_WordToExcel()

    Dim WdApp As Word.Application
    Dim WdDoc  As Document
    Dim docName As String
    Dim strFile As String
    Dim directory As String
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim Offst As Long, Txt As String

    directory = "C:\users\user\Desktop\Folder1\" ' Change to your path
    strFile = Dir(directory & "*.docx")          ' docx  extension added to prevent attempt to open other type of files

    Set Rng = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Enter row", Type:=8) '


    Set WdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    WdApp.Visible = True


    Do While strFile <> ""
    Set WdDoc = WdApp.Documents.Open(Filename:=directory & strFile)
    Rng.Offset(Offst, 0).Value = WdDoc.Name
    'First Name

    WdDoc.Tables(1).Cell(1, 3).Range.Copy           'will raise error if table& corres cell not exists , My use error handrel
    Rng.Offset(Offst, 1).Activate
    ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Format:="Text", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False    'Assumed want get name in Column B

    'is is suggested to use the below two lines instead of paste special above three lines
    'Txt = WdDoc.Tables(1).Cell(1, 3).Range.Text      'will raise error if table& corres cell not exists , My use error handrel
    'Rng.Offset(Offst, 1).Value = Txt

    WdDoc.Close SaveChanges:=False
    Offst = Offst + 1
    strFile = Dir
    Loop

WdApp.Quit
End Sub
```

It is always preferred to add reference of Microsoft Word Object library.

Comment: The document name is printing repeatedly in every cell of the row. Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: As only Start of Destination cells required  and output is dependent on Number of files in the folder. Selecting only single cell will prevent this. Otherwise may use `Rng(1,1).offset(Offst,...) ` ibstead of `Rng.Offset(Offst,`. These will treat Upper left corner cell of the selection at start of destination cell and go below down with the number files found.